# How to use nodejs request module to send request headers properly?

Tags: json, node.js, header, request

I am using `request` module for Nodejs to make http request, but there is an issue with `headers` object: the value cannot contain double quote otherwise it will be treated differently.

Basically I'm calling an API which requiring `headers` to carry a property "X-Accesstoken".

My code:

```
var userId = "123";
var url = "/users/{id}".replace("{id}", userId) ;
var token = "abcd1234"; //changed to protect the innocence, anyway it'll be the valid generated token

var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        header: {
            "x-Accesstoken": token
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };
    console.log('testing ' + url);
    request(options, function(error,response,body){
        console.log('body:' + body);
    });
```

I always got this error:

```
body:'{
  "status": 403,
  "code": 0,
  "reason": "Not authenticated"
}
```

Then if I use the Chrome Advanced REST API client, I realize the problem is because of the double quote (") in the `X-Accesstoken` inside `headers`

**With double quotes --> error:**
[image: with double quotes, got error]

**Without double quotes --> OK**
[image: without double quotes, OK]

How do I send request headers without double quotes in this case ?

Updates:
The `header` typo is the root cause, not the double quote or uppercase "X-Accesstoken". When I used Advanced REST Client to send request,  it sent the double quote as part of the headers value, thus render my token to be invalid.

Comment: 1. How do you know that the request module sent the value with double quotes? 2. Are you sure it's not just because you spelled `x-Accesstoken` with lowercase "x"?

Comment: The token in your code doesn't match your screenshot.  Are you sure the `token` var doesn't contain embedded quotes prior to sending?

Comment: @AndreasHultgren HTTP header names are case insensitive per http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: @Joe: I changed it to protect the innocence.

Comment: @AndreasHultgren : I guess you're right. I fixed the typo and change `header` to `headers`, then it works. Upvote your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `headers` instead of `header`?

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: @DioPhung If it's true that headers are case-insensitive, you can mark this one as accepted

Comment: @AndreasHultgren : yeah, request header is case-insensitive as @Joe pointed out, so the root cause here is because of typo `header` (should be `headers`). This is the correct answer.